# Eigen Objects Inside STL Containers

Tags: c++, stl, eigen

To start, I've been over and over [the page](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicStlContainers.html) referring to the issues associated with Eigen and STL containers. In my case I am doing a physical simulation and had a need to generate new points over time. I had to make the decision to used STL vectors or to implement my own kind of std::vector approach on top of the Eigen framework.

I decided to implement my points as a `std::vector<Eigen::Vector3d>` after determining that the STL container issues only apply to [fixed-size vectorizable Eigen objects](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicFixedSizeVectorizable.html), of which `Vector3d` is not (I'm pretty sure). Nonetheless, I'm getting segfaults in related areas of the code that make me think I'm not aligning things properly.

Is Vector3d truly exempt from these concerns or do I need to be worried about all the alignment issues as discussed on the Eigen pages?

Comment: Can you show the offending parts of code? [example]

Comment: Also, according to your link, there are no issues with using fixed size Eigen objects in STL containers as long as you specify the included Eigen allocator. Do I understand what that allocator does or why it's needed? Nope. Just trust the documentation.

Comment: A quick way to test if your issue is related to vectorization is compiling in debug mode. If the problem persists, it is not due to vectorization.
On top of that: `Eigen::Vector3d` is a fixed-size Eigen object. Try Eigen's aligned allocator by using `std::vector<Eigen::Vector3d, Eigen::aligned_allocator<Eigen::Vector3d>>`. Also, ensure that you have `EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW` in the public part of any class that contains fixed-size Eigen members.

Comment: Thanks @John, I can only reproduce the issue in my project, when I try to generate a MRE the issue doesn't pop up. Meaning I don't really understand it. I'm still working on making bite-sized example that fails.

Comment: @JanCa I am already compiling in Debug mode and based on my other tests I agree that it actually doesn't seem to be tied to vectorization. Regardless, I'm going through and including the "best practices" based on Eigen's recommendations to see if it clears up.

Comment: `Eigen::Vector3d` indeed does not need alignment. Segmentation faults don't have to be caused by alignment issues -- in fact if you don't deactivate asserts, Eigen should assert rather than segfault before unaligned memory access. You might be accessing memory out of range, or use memory after freeing it, etc. Did you run your program with valgrind? Or did you try compiling with address-sanitizers?

Comment: That's a head scratcher then. Check all the normal offenders: change your `vector::[]` operators to `at()`s, make sure you're not modifying your `vector`s while you're iterating through them.

Comment: @chtz Thanks for the confirmation. That's what I understood as well. Next step is valgrind but I'm on my mac at the moment so I couldn't try it immediately.

Comment: @John I'll take a look at those `[]`, which is how I've been accessing the data and still keep working on making a minimal reproducible example.